# Shipping cost not showing in Cart Review

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm running Magento 1.9.0.1. I realized now that the shipping cost is not showing on the final review before buying. When the sales email is sent, it displays accurately the shipping, but on the review it doesn't appear (so people feel dissapointed)

I once installed MatrixRate extension, but then disabled it. I installed a fresh Magento over my old DB. The files are all new and there's no extension related to shipping installed (only 2 installed, and have nothing to do with it). I tried with the default template (because maybe I changed something there) but it's the same thing. The code isn't there, is not that it isn't showing, it just isn't there (if you go to View Source Code, there's nothing). I haven't changed anything on the template, and even tried with the default one and it's the same issue.

I'm thinking this has two options: the DB is corrupted, but that would be weird because I over-installed it with a fresh one, and also generally that has nothing to do with that, those are template issues.
The other option is that I changed something in the configuration but can't figure it out what could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if "Mage_Tax" is enabled. System->Configuration->Advanced.

Check your Settings in System->Configuration->Sales->Tax